# Use Gstreamer pipelines on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox, gstreamer, hackintosh

I am trying to develop Gstreamer(1.0) application for the Mac OS X, for this aim I want to use some Hackintosh distribution. But I got a lot of problems related to the Hackintosh installation on VirtualBox, Gstreamer installation on Mac OS X, and using Gstreamer on Mac OS X. There is no need to enumerate these troubles because they all really diverse and are not connected(also of course I already tried to resolve them).

So my question is: **how I can install and use Gstreamer pipelines on Hackintosh?**

**This question has nested items about which Mac OS X distribution I need to use, how should I install it, on which virtualization software I need to install this, which Gstreamer version I need to use, and how should I install Gstreamer(etc.)?**

P.S. I know that this is rather abstract question but I already tried to resolve these problems one by one and got nothing.

Comment: there may be always problems with video on virtual box - mainly with OpenGL..

Comment: @otopolsky ok, and what can i do to resolve these problems?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that - I just heard something on [irc of gstreamer](http://irc.lc/freenode/gstreamer) - you can ask also there .. but I guess the solution is not to use virtualbox (or any virtualisation)..

Answer (score -2):

Try [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install gstreamer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I always use homebrew

Comment: So you should probably know how to install things using Homebrew :-)

Comment: Yes, I know :) 
But I have different problems with Gstreamer when I use pipelines(issues with audio and video).

Comment: So you can ask questions :-)